# How to retrieve the all documents of an array except one document which contains field of a particular value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.sample.find():
 {_id:1, locations: [{vname: "edd", distr: "prakasam"}, {vname: "vij", distr: "krishna"}, {vname: "kakani", distr: "guntur"}]};
```

I want to find the locations other than `vname: "vij"`

My result could be

```
{_id: 1, locations: [{vname: "edd", distr: "prakasam"}, {vname: "kakani", distr: "guntur"}]};
```

I tried with the following queries but couldn't helped me out.

```
db.sample.find({'locations.$.vname': {$ne: 'vij'}})
```

It is returning entire document but I need to exclude this document.

Any Help is appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$redact`. `$$PRUNE` when `locations` array matches `vname` as `vij`

```
db.sample.aggregate({
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
                $eq: ["$vname", "vij"]
            },
            "$$PRUNE",
            "$$DESCEND"
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about "$redact"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032549/122005

Comment: Awesome, it's really helped me alot. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> db.sample.find({"locations.vname": {$ne: "vij"}})
```

Comment: Not working, I tried.

Comment: Just from my mongo shell - works. What is your MongoDB version? Are you using a shell?

Comment: Version 3.2.6 ,
I'm using cmd prompt in windows.

Comment: Try to start Mongo Shell and do the same inside shell. Just type mongo in cmd

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried however you said but couldn't able to success.
Got the solution in another comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the `location` is an array of objects in your schema, you can't exclude a particular object from the result. You can exclude the whole `location` field from the result. However, you have an option to run aggregation on your collection.

```
db.sample.aggregate([
     {
        "$match" :{"_id":1}
     }, 
     {
        "$unwind" :"$locations"
     },
     {
        "$match" :{
           "locations.vname":{"$ne": "vij"}
         }
     }
    ])
```

This will return data in this form.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "locations" : { "vname" : "edd", "distr" : "prakasam" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "locations" : { "vname" : "kakani", "distr" : "guntur" } }
```

Comment: This is fine, But I need the output as mentioned in the post. 
That too "locations" field type is getting changed rather than array it is becoming an object/document.

Could you help to get in that format. Thankyou.